# Unable to use perform_create to make a reverse relationship between two model

Tags: api, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, django-rest-framework

I have three models, **"Item" , "Seller" and "User"** .
**User** is like admin he can create **Seller** and each **Seller** will have a unique id suppose "uid".
And The **Sellers** created by **User** can create **Item** , So I want to make API in which if a **Seller** creates/posts a new **Item** , I want a reverse relationship between (User and Seller) and (Seller and Item). i.e Every Seller created by User should have a field that have all Seller he created. And every seller should have a filed telling the name of User who created it. Simillary between Seller and Item .Every Seller will have list of Items he created and every Item will have a filed Seller who created it.

Now I have implemented User and Seller Reverse Relationship but I am not able to create Seller and Item reverse relation. I followed these link [Tutorial 4: Authentication & Permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) and [Serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/). 
Here is my code snippet :

Model.py

```
class Seller(models.Model):
 UID=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
 name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
 ....
 super_owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='seller_added') 

 def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s'  (self.UID)

class Item(models.Model):
 name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
 ....
 seller_uid= models.ForeignKey(Seller,related_name='items_added', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


 def __unicode__(self):
 return '%s: %d' % (self.name, self.mrp)
```

Serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 seller_added = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Seller.objects.all()) 
 class Meta:
 model = User
 fields = ('id', 'username','seller_added')


class SellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 items_added = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True) 
 super_owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='super_owner.username')  


  class Meta:
   model = Seller
   fields = ('UID','name','items_added','super_owner')


class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 seller_uid= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='seller_uid.UID') 

  class Meta:
   model = Item
   fields = ('id', 'name', 'seller_uid')
```

Views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly_seller,)



    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(seller_uid=self.request.user.seller_uid)    


class SellerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Seller.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SellerSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(super_owner=self.request.user)
```

**I dont know what should I write in perform_create of ItemViewSet ??**
In **Seller** Model the filed **super_owner** is initilised from method **perfom_create** by using `super_owner=self.request.user`. Similary I want to initialise the filed **seller_uid**  declared in **Item** Model.  On removing this line from **ItemSerializer** `seller_uid=serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='seller_uid.UID')` and deleting **perform_create** from **SellerViewSet**. My api works but when i post it asks to select the **Seller** which i want to use as foreign key. But I want to do this thing automatic. As In case of super_owner. In simple word what should write in the **perform_create** of **ItemViewSet** To set the **seller_uid** directly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that `super_owner` written in `ReadOnlyField` so your serializer doesn't read it. Just remove that field and use default one. Now you'll be able to send `user.id` to it and you can also delete `perform_create`.
If you want a special representation though you can override `to_representation` serializers method:

```
class SellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items_added = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Seller
        fields = ('UID','name','items_added','super_owner')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(SellerSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['super_owner'] = instance.super_owner.username
        return representation
```

Comment: Hii thanks for the answer.It helped me to some other way. But my question was something else. In **Seller** Model the filed **super_owner** is initilised from method **perfom_create** by using `super_owner=self.request.user`. Similary I want to initialise the filed of seller_uid  declared in Item Model. By removing seller_uid= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='seller_uid.UID')

Comment: @BhupendraSinghChauhan sorry, I don't get you problem, you want to create a link from `Seller` model to `Item`? or create an `Item` while you creating `Seller`? In a first case, you could just remove `StringRelatedField` and just write `items_added` in a field, so you'll be able to pass `id`s to of `Item` to `items_added` field. If you want to create `Item`, you should override a `create` method in `Seller` serizlier or move that logic in `Seller` manager, it is common way to create two related models.

Comment: Sry I have edited my question. I think it will be clear now. I want to link Seller and Item. Thanks

Comment: @BhupendraSinghChauhan so what a problem remove this field ` seller_uid= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='seller_uid.UID')` from Item serializer like you did with `SelerSerializer` and pass a seller id into this field?

Comment: Yes i have already removed this line. After this when i use item api it has a seller_uid attribute , and now i have to select from a dropdown of all created seller, the seller i want to choose as foreign key. So my doubt it is, if make a post request using this api form some application. Will I have to set the seller_uid normally as all other attributes in Item are editable/writable but seller_uid has a dropdown. @ivan